# Python 2.7 Trying to narrow a list using range and duplicate

Tags: python, duplicates, range

```
from numpy import *

import collections

array = [28000,35200,35200,35200,35700,36000]

rng = range(35000,37000)

for elem in array:

    print elem
```

35200 35700 36000

That gets me off to a good start, but I need only the duplicates from the range list, which would only be 35200. I tried adding a line under print elem, for example-

```
print elem

print [x for x, y in collections.Counter(a).items if y > 1]
```

But I get `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`. The duplicate will be needed later for an equation. How can I narrow array down to just the duplicate within a range?

Comment: Don't call a list `array` since it shadows the module with the same name...

Comment: Not to mention it shadows the `array` function imported by `numpy`

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's `a`? By "I need only the duplicates from the range list", do you mean only the elements that appear multiple times in `array`, or only the elements that also appear in `rng`? What's `rng` even for?

Comment: Is `array` necessarily sorted?

Answer (score 1):

`items` is a function, you forgot the `()`:

```
counterItems = collections.Counter(a).items()
print [x for x, y in counterItems if y > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
In [15]: a = [28000,35200,35200,35200,35700,36000]

In [16]: set([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])
Out[16]: set([35200])
```

Comment: This is `O(n²)` whereas the original is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy` way of doing it will be:

```
>>> a=np.array([28000,35200,35200,35200,35700,36000])
>>> a[np.sum(a==a[...,np.newaxis], axis=1)>1]
array([35200, 35200, 35200])
>>> np.unique(a[np.sum(a==a[...,np.newaxis], axis=1)>1])
array([35200])
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption of `a` being sorted, this is probably the fastest way (with `numpy`), including the range restriction:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([28000,35000,35200,35200,35200,35200,35700,36000])

left = a.searchsorted(35000, "left")
right = a.searchsorted(37000, "right")
section = a[left:right]
numpy.unique(section[section[1:] == section[:-1]])
#>>> array([35200])
```

Similar speedups can be found by using the `bisect` module on regular non-numpy arrays.